# Functional Site Testing using Mocha and Chai for Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, functional-testing, chai

I am having difficulty understanding the following code that utilizes mocha and chai for site testing in nodejs:

```
suite('Global Tests', function(){
        test('page has a valid title', function(){
                assert(document.title && document.title.match(/\S/) &&
                        document.title.toUpperCase() === 'AHC');
        });
});
```

What is confusing is how this code is working yet does not seem to follow the [chai documentation](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/) for assert. Where the format is as follows:

assert(expression, message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just not passing the second parameter (the message).   This is not invalid is just makes it more difficult to determine why the test failed.  If you wanted to make the test cleaner you could break the expression into three asserts  and pass a message about what the assert if verifying.

```
suite('Global Tests', function(){
  test('page has a valid title', function(){
    assert(document.title, 'document title is not defined');
    assert(document.title.match(/\S/), 'document title does not have a single character');
    assert(document.title.toUpperCase() === 'AHC', 'Document title does not equal AHC');
    });
});
```

Comment: I have added assert('foo' !== 'bar', 'foo is not bar'); to test how the message works. I placed it in different parts of the code above and not able see the message "foo is not bar". Can you provide an example of multiple asserts with the code above?

Comment: Updated answer with an example.  If you would like to see the message I suggest changing the 'AHC' value in the third assert. Note that your assert example 'foo' !== 'bar' is always true so the assertion is never occurring.

Comment: I ran your code and what I am finding is the message being displayed in the browser 'page has a valid title' (with either a check or X depending on is it passes) and not the message associated with the assert statement. Should the assert message be displayed in the browser?

Comment: The assert message will only be displayed if the assertion fails. change AHC in the third assert to FOO. Then you should see an X and the assertion message I believe.

Comment: You are right about the message showing when it fails. The problem though happens when two assert fail. I placed document.title === 'ABC and anther assert to document.title.toUpperCase() === 'foo'. What I find is only the first assert failing for ABC is displayed and the other failing assert is not displayed. This part is beyond the scope of my question, however, the multiple asserts will require separate test functions to get displayed in the browser. This is what I found through testing your code. Thank you